# What really is the difference between $\mathbf{v}=(2,3) $ and $\mathbf{u}=(2,3,0)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I used to believe that there is no difference between $\mathbf{v}=(2,3)$ which is a vector lying in $xy$ plane and $\mathbf{u}=(2,3,0)$ which is a three dimensional vector but still lying in $xy$ plane. So, for me both the vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and  $\mathbf{u}$ were same. The analogy I used was that both the tail and head coincide for $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{u}$.

But on the second page of the textbook I am using as reference (Gilbert Strang-Introduction to linear algebra), I found something different . The author says,

*The vector $(x,y)$ in a plane is different from vector $(x,y,0)$ in $3-$space*.

That's it. Since this statement is not well explained there so I am here. Hoping for help.

Since I am beginning the Linear algebra course so Please show some tolerance. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

They're different because they're members of different vector spaces. After all, the vector $(2,3)$ is defined with respect to the standard basis $e_1, e_2$; what's to say that the vector $(2,3,0)$ has been defined wrt a basis whose first two vectors are $e_1, e_2$ and whose third vector is orthogonal to those two?

If you wanted to abuse notation, you could write that $(2,3) = (2,3,0)$. But this is so non-standard that it would confuse everyone who read it. There's no good reason, for instance, that you should miss out the *third* component rather than the *second*: why don't you have $(2,3) = (2,0,3) = (2,0)$?

Vector spaces often don't canonically embed into other vector spaces, so there's often no canonical way of identifying a vector in one space with a vector in another.

Comment: I think I m confusing things here.. what does vector (2,3) means?? Doesn't that mean x component equals 2, y component equals 3 and z component is 0??

Comment: $(2,3)$ is a vector in the space of real pairs. It does not have a $z$ component. Read what @Patrick has said again.

Comment: I can't have (2,3,0)=(2,0)=(2,3) as I have to take care of equality of components which I followed while saying (2,3,0)=(2,3).

Comment: You didn't follow an equality. $(2,3)$ **does not have** a $z$-component to even compare!

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra But why were you justified in removing the *final* zero component rather than, say, the *first* zero component? That is, why is $(0,2,3)$ not equal to $(2,3)$? (That's just what happens if you rotate the space through 90 degrees, and I'm sure you agree that equality shouldn't change under rotation.)

Comment: Well yes, then what I m doing wrong?? I am considering a component equal to 0 which doesn't even exist?

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra That is what you are doing wrong, yes.

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra There are several ways one can view a plane as being part of the greater space $\mathbb{R}^3$, and no one of those ways is mathematically distinguished over the others. One could take the $x,y$-plane, the $y,z$-plane, the plane perpendicular to the vector $(1,3,2)$ through the origin, and so on. All these ways are basically equivalent, and in all of them, $(2,3)$ refers to a different vector in the greater $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 3):

The vector $(2, 3)$ is an element of the two-dimensional vector space $\mathbb R^2$. The vector $(2, 3, 0)$ is an element of the three-dimensional vector space $\mathbb R^3$. What is the difference between the two?

There are infinitely many ways of **embedding** $\mathbb R^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$. By "embedding," we mean an **injective isomorphism of vector spaces**. The image of an embedding $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ is just a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ which contains the origin $(0, 0, 0)$, so the choice of an embedding is (sort of) equivalent to the choice of a plane through the origin. There are infinitely many such planes, and each plane can be thought of as a "copy" of $\mathbb R^2$ sitting inside of $\mathbb R^3$.

When you think of $(2, 3)$ as the same as $(2, 3, 0)$, what you are really doing is thinking of $\mathbb R^2$ as the $(x, y)$-plane in $\mathbb R^3$, as you said. In this case you have chosen to embed $\mathbb R^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$ via the map $(x, y) \mapsto (x, y, 0)$. But there are infinitely many other embeddings you could have chosen.

I think the point the author of your textbook is trying to make is this: elements of two-dimensional vector spaces are not elements of three-dimensional vector spaces. If you want to consider elements of $\mathbb R^2$ as elements of $\mathbb R^3$, you have to choose an embedding.

Answer (score 2):

They are different because for example we can't add or subtract them. Try ;)

Comment: Well, I can think of a way to add and subtract them. It is just not the usual addition in $\Bbb R^2$ or in $\Bbb R^3$ (though it could be quite similar to the latter). I don't think this kind of reasoning is very helpful. I _can_ add $3\in \Bbb R$ to a polynomial, to a function, and even to an $n\times n$ matrix, but that does not make $3$ a polynomial, a function, or a matrix.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Hmm, such addition would be far beyond the standard definition of addition in vector spaces.   If we use non-standard definitions of operations we could do in fact almost everything, it would be interesting  for example how we could define, proposed by you, addition of a number to a matrix ? I think, if possible, it could be made with several ways.

Comment: You did not say "add in a specific vector space", just "add", and that is what I was criticising. One can add (the imaginary unit) $\mathbf i$ to $-2$, although one cannot do this using the addition of the real vector space $\Bbb R$ in which $-2$ lives; making the distinction is needed. As for adding numbers to square matrices, they are interpreted, as in _any_ (unitary) ring, as that multiple of the multiplicative unit, here the identity matrix$~I_n$. Such a convention is needed for identities like the binomial formula (in commutative rings): its coefficients are _numbers_, not ring elements.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Interesting procedure,... thank you for the explanation.